# systemd service not enabling

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd

I need your help to enable a service that starts and executes on boot a program that I have made. The program is a command line one and takes parameters through the flags therefore in **/etc** the service conf file looks like this

```
  GNU nano 4.8                                                                                      ip-tracker.conf                                                                                                
SERVER=-server=smtp.gmail.com
PORT=-port=587
USER=-user=supdosedlyMyUsername
PASS=-password=supdosedlyMyPassword
FROM=-from=amyEmailUser@gmail.com
TO=-to=myEmailUser@gmail.com
```

and in **/lib/systemd/myProgram.service** looks like this

```
[Unit]
Description=Some description for the service

[Service]
Type=simple
#Restart=always
#RestartSec=5s
EnvironmentFile=/etc/mySuperProgram.conf

# HERE I GET MY VALUES FROM conf file FOR THE PROGRAM FLAGS 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ip-tracker $SERVER $PORT $USER $PASS $FROM $TO

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The issue is the following, if I try to enable the service before I run

```
sudo systemctl start myService
```

I get no error in console and if I run

```
sudo systemctl status myService
```

I get this

```
ip-tracker.service - tracking your ip after system reboot
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ip-tracker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-04-22 18:14:46 EEST; 39min ago
   Main PID: 925 (code=exited, status=2)

apr 22 18:14:46 dev ip-tracker[925]: [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x40 pc=0x642f9f]
apr 22 18:14:46 dev ip-tracker[925]: goroutine 19 [running]:
apr 22 18:14:46 dev ip-tracker[925]: main.getIp(0xc00013e060)
apr 22 18:14:46 dev ip-tracker[925]:         /home/adi/Projects/ip_finder/main.go:27 +0xff
apr 22 18:14:46 dev ip-tracker[925]: main.main.func1()
apr 22 18:14:46 dev ip-tracker[925]:         /home/adi/Projects/ip_finder/main.go:112 +0x26
apr 22 18:14:46 dev ip-tracker[925]: created by main.main
apr 22 18:14:46 dev ip-tracker[925]:         /home/adi/Projects/ip_finder/main.go:111 +0xb1
apr 22 18:14:46 dev systemd[1]: ip-tracker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
apr 22 18:14:46 dev systemd[1]: ip-tracker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

If I run

```
sudo systemctl start myService
```

the service starts and does is supposed to do...
Then if I run the command to enable it I get no error message but if I check the status it says that is not active as per below:

```
ip-tracker.service - tracking your ip after system reboot
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ip-tracker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2022-04-22 18:54:40 EEST; 10min ago
    Process: 13189 ExecStart=/usr/bin/ip-tracker $SERVER $PORT $USER $PASS $FROM $TO (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 13189 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

apr 22 18:54:36 dev systemd[1]: Started tracking your ip after system reboot.
apr 22 18:54:37 dev ip-tracker[13189]: ISV  true
apr 22 18:54:40 dev systemd[1]: ip-tracker.service: Succeeded
```

How to enable my service and remain like this?

Thank you

Comment: My guess would be that you're starting before the network is stable so whatever getIP() is doing is failing and you're not checking return codes properly.  In your [Unit] section try adding `After=network.target`

Comment: @StephenHarris I have added the line but still I cannot enable the service, the status after a reboot is:
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ip-tracker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-04-23 15:44:20 EEST; 3min 4s ago
    Process: 1067 ExecStart=/usr/bin/ip-tracker $SERVER $PORT $USER $PASS $FROM $TO (code=exited, status=2)
.
.
.
apr 23 15:44:20 dev systemd[1]: ip-tracker.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT

the program is calling a public API, get the external IP and mail it to me.